# How can I make Ctrl + Alt act like Alt gr in Ubuntu?

Tags: x11, keyboard, xkb

I recently switched to Ubuntu on my laptop and one thing that almost got me to switch back to Windows is the fact that I can't make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to act like <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>.

I have programmed for several years and for example I'm used to make the symbol `$` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>. Here in Ubuntu I have to use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> which almost makes me insane...

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: have you tried playing with the mappings of the composekey?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey

Comment: You can use `xmodmap` command to do this.
Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/5095/typing-using-key-combinations

Comment: Try xmodmap, which is available in the x11-xserver-utils package in ubuntu. It allows you to remap any key combination.

Comment: @elitasson If you find out the answer to your own question, please psot it as a separate answer.

Comment: @Bernhard No, you can't do this with xmodmap. It doesn't support making the Ctrl+Alt combination a distinct modifier. But I think you can [with xkb](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312772/making-ctrl-alt-act-like-altgr-in-xkb).

Comment: @Bernhard I meant @Bichoy and didn't pay attention to the completion of `@B`, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only use the special signs when I write code so I managed to fix this is Sublime Text.

In Preferences -> Key bindings - User

insert the following:

```
[
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+2"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "@"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+3"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "£"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+4"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "$"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+5"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "€"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+7"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "{"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+8"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "["} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+9"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "]"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+0"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "}"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt++"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\\"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+<"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "|"} }
```

]

Answer (score 7):

You could add global shortcuts to write special chars. I use this often for my German keyboard layout with Ubuntu (on Windows this work out of the box).

I added the following shortcuts:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> to write the letter `{`

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to write the letter `}`

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to write the letter `[`

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to write the letter `]`

To add these shortcuts you will need `xbindkeys` and `xvkbd`:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xvkbd
```

Then edit the configuration file:

```
vim ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

And add the following lines (edit them as you prefer):

```
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '{'"
    m:0xc + c:16
    Control+Alt + 7

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '['"
    m:0xc + c:17
    Control+Alt + 8

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text ']'"
    m:0xc + c:18
    Control+Alt + 9

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '}'"
    m:0xc + c:19
    Control+Alt + 0

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[backslash]'"
    m:0xc + c:20
    Control+Alt + ssharp

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[asciitilde]'"
    m:0xc + c:35
    Control+Alt + plus
```

Then reload xbindkeys:

```
xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

*Thanks to whizz for sharing this (http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/strg-%2B-alt-alt-gr-wie-in-windows/).*

Comment: Could you explain what the lines m:0xc + c:XX does?

Comment: I know this is an old question and answer, but just for those who want to add more characters like | or @ or €:
The key codes used at `c:XX` are, as far as I know, not universal, so you won't have luck googling that. You can however find out a key code locally by installing and executing "xev" in your command line. It will print all of your keyboard and mouse actions, so you'll have to scroll a bit to find "your" character.

Comment: For example, pressing < (to configure |) while running xev prints this out:
`KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x7e, subw 0x0, time 35363548, (135,60), root:(903,472),
    state 0x0, keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XFilterEvent returns: False`
The number you need is always in the third line, after "keycode". So in this case, 94.

Answer (score 3):

After trying and failing to get it to work with a combination of xbindkeys and xvkbd/xte (I could never get certain characters {, [, ], }, \, etc. to behave properly perhaps because I use a Scandinavian keyboard layout), I finally found a simple and practical solution: Autokey. Here are the exact instructions to get it working:

1. Install **Autokey** through Ubuntu Software (I used the GTK-version, not KDE) or by: “sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk”.
2. Configure one script per key, e.g. for { use this code: `keyboard.send_keys("<alt_gr>+7")` and set the hotkey to Ctrl+Alt+7 (first set hotkey to 7 then add Ctrl and Alt as modifiers). This at least worked for the most important code-writing keys: { [ ] } .
3. Add autokey to Startup Applications (search for “start” to find it) and then add a program with “autokey” as the command.

This solution will work for anything running in the current X-session (I think) but will not work if you start a new terminal session using Ctrl+Alt+(F2-F6).

Comment: not working in GNOME 42.1 under Wayland. Tried both autokey-gtk and autokey-qt

Answer (score 2):

Although this still doesn't answer your question, I find this to be an easier solution than the other answers.

To make <kbd>R-ALT</kbd> work like <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, you can add the following line to your `~/.xinitrc`:

```
setxkbmap -option lv3:ralt_switch
```

Other ways to shift to the 3rd level (that which is usually achieved using <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key) can found, and new ways can be defined in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/level3`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to make the <kbd>L-Alt</kbd> key act exactly the same as the <kbd>Altgr</kbd> key.
I didn't try with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> key

It consists in modifying the level3 file

In the terminal, change directory :

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols
```

make a copy of the level3 file :

```
sudo cp level3 level3.old
```

edit level3 with any text editor :

```
sudo gedit level3
```

You should find a block like this :

```
  key <RALT> {
    type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1] = [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
    };
  modifier_map Mod5   { ISO_Level3_Shift };
```

Add a copy of the block with LALT (left alt) instead of RALT (altgr) :

```
  key <LALT> {
    type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1] = [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
    };
  modifier_map Mod5   { ISO_Level3_Shift };
```

Now, there should be 3 other blocks starting with `key <RALT>`

Do the same with them.

Save and quit.