# Making CTRL + ALT act like AltGr in xkb

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to make <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> act like AltGr, and from this post (1st answer):

[unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84707/how-can-i-make-ctrl-alt-act-like-alt-gr-in-ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84707/how-can-i-make-ctrl-alt-act-like-alt-gr-in-ubuntu)

I have gotten to the point where I have the  level3 file open i gedit.. So I have to change the `key <RALT>` to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd>, but how do I specify that the two keys need to be pressed? `key<LCTL + LALT>` or `<LCTL> <LALT>` or what?

Running Linux Mint 18 Sarah 64-bit Cinnamon if that is of any significance.

Would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working using a combination of xbindkeys and xvkbd. You need to install both of these packages to make my solution work.

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
xbindkeys --defaults > /home/your-user-name/.xbindkeysrc
sudo apt-get install xvkbd
```

You will need to open the .xbindkeysrc file in a text-editor for example `gedit .xbindkeysrc` You can then just remove the entire content of that file and type:

`"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "{""
 m:0xc + c:16
 Control+Alt + 7`

This will make <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> type {

Just follow this pattern for 8,9,0 or whatever keys you want to change up and you won't even remember that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> didn't work. The only place this does not work is in the terminal. I would still be interested for a solution in xkbd but just thought I would add this here so that other people with this problem find a solution :)